# Using re to capture text between key words over the course of a doc

Tags: python, regex, string, search

I am trying to capture text between key words in a document and the keys words themselves.

For example, let's say I have multiple instances of "egg" in a string. I want to capture each work between "egg" and "egg."

I have tried:

```
import re
text = "egg hashbrowns egg bacon egg fried milk egg"
re.findall(r"(/egg) (.*) (/egg)", text)
```

I have also tried `re.match` and `re.search`.

What I usually get is `("egg"), ("hashbrowns egg bacon egg fried milk"), ("egg")`

What I need to get is `(egg, hashbrown, egg), (egg, bacon egg), (egg, fried, milk, egg)`.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a non-greedy match.  The `*?` is a non-greedy form of `*`, and matches the smallest possible sequence.  Also, `/egg` matches exactly that, but I assume you just want `egg`, so your actual regex becomes `(egg) (.*?) (egg)`.  However, since regular expressions consume the string as it is matched, you need to use look-ahead and look-behind assertions to match the intermediate text.  In this case, `(?<=egg) (.*?) (?=egg)` finds text with "egg" before and after, but only returns the inbetween stuff, i.e. `['hashbrowns', 'bacon', 'fried milk']`.  Trying to match "egg" too would be quite a lot more complicated, and would probably involve parsing the string twice, so its only worth going into it if that's actually what you want.

All this is documented in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), so look there for more info.

Comment: Actually, I've used that permutation too. It still doesn't work because this also captures the intervening egg. I need to capture what is between each span of egg, not the first and last instances of egg.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that.  You need to use look-ahead and look-behind assertions.  I'll update my answer.