# Python Regular Expression findall with variable

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use re.findall with look-behind and look-forward to extract data. The regular expression works fine when I am not using a raw_input variable, but I need users to be able to input a variety of different search terms.

Here is the current code:

```
me = re.findall(r"(?<='(.+)'+variable+'(.+)')(.*?)(?='(.+)+variable+(.+)')", raw)
```

As you can see, I am trying to pull out strings between one search term.

However, each time I use this type of formatting, I get a fixed width error. Is there anyway around this?

I have also tried the following formats with no success.

```
variable = raw_input('Term? ')
'.*' + variable + '.*'
```

and

```
'.*%s.*' % (variable, )
```

and

```
'.*{0}.*'.format(variable)
```

and

```
 '.*{variable}.*'.format(variable=variable)
```

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here. The `'`'s and `+`'s in your expression are part of your raw string, so you're not doing concatenation.

Comment: Can you provide an example string and what you want to be able to extract?

Comment: The string would be something like this: raw = "fish, hook, swallowed, reeled, boat, fish." I would like to capture all the words between fish if fish is set as the variable. Output would be: "hook, swallowed, reeled, boat, fish."

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746721/using-re-to-capture-text-between-key-words-over-the-course-of-a-doc

Comment: No, this is a different question. That question was answered. I am now seeing how to use raw_input variables to guide the regular expressions search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but it may get you started. As far as I understand your question, you don't need lookaheads or lookbehinds. This is for Python 2.x (won't work with Python 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> string_to_search = 'fish, hook, swallowed, reeled, boat, fish'
>>> entered_by_user = 'fish'
>>> search_regex = r"{0}(.+){0}".format(entered_by_user)
>>> match = re.search(search_regex, string_to_search)
>>> if match:
...     print "result:", match.group(1).strip(' ,')
...
result: hook, swallowed, reeled, boat
```

If you really want the last 'fish' in the result as in your comment above, then just remove the second `{0}` from the `format()` string.

Comment: I just realized how unclear I've been. I do apologize and thank the posters for their patience. The problem with the above search method is that if I have multiple terms in the string (e.g. "fish, hook, fish, catch, reel, fish") then I will only get what is between the first and last "fish." I do need each word between each instance of "fish." I have no problem doing this with the look-behind and look-forward methods; but, I can't use raw_input to the guide the search.

Comment: Does this solution do what you want if you add `?` after the `+`? In other words, `search_regex = r"{0}(.+?){0}".format(entered_by_user)`

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work:

```
me = re.findall(rf"(?<='(.+)'+{variable}+'(.+)')(.*?)(?='(.+)+{variable}+(.+)')", raw)
```

You also can add many different variables as you wish.
Add **rf** for the regular expression and the desired variables in between {}

```
import re

text = "regex is the best"    
var1 = "is the"
var2 = "best"
yes = re.findall(rf"regex {var1} {var2}", text)

print(yes)
```

['regex is the best']

Answer (score 0):

The way lookbehind is usually implemented (including its Python implementation) has an inherent limitation that you are unfortunately running into: lookbehinds cannot be variable-length. The "Important Notes About Lookbehind" section [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) explains why. I think you should be able to do the regex without a lookbehind, though.