# Python - How to find and save all word between two specific strings

Tags: python, regex, string, search

while searching I found this [threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746721/using-re-to-capture-text-between-key-words-over-the-course-of-a-doc). This is quiet close to what I need.

Which leads directly to my first Problem:

The string I have is:

```
line = <draw:line draw:style-name="gr1" draw:text-style-name="P1" draw:layer="layout" svg:x1="0cm" svg:y1="0cm" svg:x2="3.5cm" svg:y2="2.7cm">
```

I need to extract the values after the svg:x1= tags. So I tried

```
print re.findall(r"(?<=svg:x1) (.*?) (?=svg:y1)", line)
```

But nothing except [] is printed.

The second Problem is I then tried something like

```
line = 'string1 string2 string3'
```

and then

```
print re.findall(r"(?<=string1) (.*?) (?=string3)", line)
```

which gives what I want, but when I try

```
file.write(re.findall(r"(?<=string1) (.*?) (?=string3)", line))
```

(The file I want to write to is of course defined before, so I can write stuff to it)

I get "TypeError: expected a character buffer object"

So now my question in one complete sentence:
How can I extract a string between to specific strings and save it in a file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717856/any-good-and-gentle-python-regexp-tutorials-out-there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
In [10]: re.findall('svg:x1="([^"]*)"', line)
Out[10]: ['0cm']
```

Edit:

```
re.findall('svg:x1="(\d*)cm"', line)

In [11]: re.findall('svg:x1="(\d*)cm"', line)
Out[11]: ['0']
```

Comment: I want to have that without the "cm". But that seems really nice. Would you please try to explain why the "" are excluded on the output, I tried to understand while reading the docs, but since english is not my native language this seems a bit hard to me.

Comment: Both the " are outside the inter ().

Answer (score 2):

The following regex

```
print re.findall(r"(?<=svg:x1) (.*?) (?=svg:y1)", line)
```

you wrote expects a space after svg:x1 which is not the case in your original string. The correct regex would be

```
print re.findall(r"(?<=svg:x1)(.*?)(?= svg:y1)", line)
```

The regex expression you wrote returns a list. You will have to iterate the list to write the items to the file.

```
data=re.findall(r"(?<=svg:x1)(.*?)(?= svg:y1)", line)
fl.write(' '.join(data))
```

Don't use `file` as a variable. It is a reserved word in Python.

Comment: It's probably more efficient to replace the `for` loop with `fl.write(' '.join(match))`.

Comment: @KyleStrand You are right. I have edited the solution and implemented what you suggested.

Comment: Seems nice, but how can I remove the "" and the cm so that I only recive the integer?

Comment: Replacing `(.*)` with this `[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d+]` should return the int

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex, something like this.

```
def get_middle_text(line, string_start, string_end):
    temp = line.split(string_start)[1]
    return temp.split(string_end)[0]


result = get_middle_text(line, 'string1', 'string2')
```

Edit:

If you can have multiple matches you can do something like below, and return field of matches:

```
def get_middle_text(line, string_start, string_end):
    tmp = line.split(string_start)
    result = []
    if len(tmp) == 1:
        return result
    for x in range(1, len(tmp)):
        temp = tmp[x].split(string_end)[0]
        result.append(temp)
    return result
```

Comment: The problem with this is that since multiple values must be extracted, this function must be called multiple times, which is inefficient. @jitendra's regex solution is better.